# Google Web Search API (Deprecated) requests limit

Tags: api, search

Developer's Guid for Google Web Search API (Deprecated) informs, that the number of requests you may make per day will be limited. But I can't find information about how much requests I can make... What the limitation is?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the limit is 1000 requests per day:

http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#tech7