# Google Web Search API limitation

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Web Search API (Deprecated) requests limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212223/google-web-search-api-deprecated-requests-limit)

There is some limitation to use Google Web Search API (in Java) to search 650,000 diferent words?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to search them as one query, yes, there's almost certainly a limitation on the length of the query you can send (though I don't know what it is off the top of my head).

If you mean individually, then you'll have to contend with their [free usage rules](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview):

> **Free quota**
>
> Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day.
>
> **Paid Usage**
>
> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day. If you need additional quota, please request additional quota from the console.

Answer (score 0):

It is unknown what the limit is, but it is definitely limited.

As per this article: https://developers.google.com/web-search/ the Web Search API has been depreciated and you should use the Custom Search API (link is in that article).

Update to the new stuff!